# creating a list of company news stories and matching dates

Tags: python, list, parsing

I'm attempting to create a list which groups a company stock symbol with a news headline and its corresponding date.

The head of the data essentially looks like the following:

```
<a href="https://invst.ly/y99fg" rel="nofollow"
target="_blank" class="js-external-link img">

<img class="lazyload" data-src="https://i-invdn-
com.investing.com/news/LYNXNPEA9D0VD_S.jpg" 
onerror="javascript:this.src='https://i-invdn-
com.investing.com/news/news-paper_108x81.png'" alt="Will 
Netflix Stock See a Boost From Stranger Things?" />
</a>
<div class="textDiv">
<a href="https://invst.ly/y99fg" class="js-external-link
title" title="Will Netflix Stock See a Boost From Stranger 
Things?" rel="nofollow" target="_blank">Will Netflix Stock  
See a Boost From Stranger Things?</a>
<div class="articleDetails"><span>By 247wallst</span><span e>
hreat" />
</a>
```

I've manage to sucefully extract the date and stock symbol but I cannot figure out how to group the date with its associated news heading.

```
parsed_data = []

for stock , stock_news_table in stock_news_tables.items():

    date_data = re.findall(r'[A-Z][a-z]{2} \d{1,2}, \d{4}' , str(stock_news_table))

    headline = stock_news_table

    #print(date_data)

    parsed_data.append([stock , date_data , headline])
```

The output so far looks like the following. As you can see the headlines are split where there are multiple new lines: \n\n\n\n .

```
 [['Netflix',
  ['May 19, 2022',
   'May 18, 2022',
   'May 18, 2022',
   'May 18, 2022',
   'May 18, 2022',
   'May 17, 2022',
   'May 10, 2022',
   'May 09, 2022',
   'May 02, 2022'],
  "\n\n\n\n\n\nFord Unloads More Shares in Electric-Vehicle Startup Rivian\nBy The 
   Wall Street Journal\xa0-\xa020 hours ago\nFord sold 7 million Rivian shares at a 
   price of $26.88, the company says. That followed an 8-million-share sale earlier 
   in the week at about the same price.\n\n\n\n\n \nFord sells shares in EV maker 
   Rivian for $188.2 million\nBy Reuters\xa0-\xa0May 14, 2022  (Reuters) - Ford 
   Motor (NYSE:F) Co sold 7 million shares of electric carmaker Rivian Aut
```

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure if it's even possible using a regex. It requires analyzing the text, as the formats are completely different, e.g. `20 hours ago` as date, the symbol doesn't always exist, and it's pretty inconsistent. The only keywords you might be able to use is `\n By .*? -\xa(.*?)\n` to get the time and then `\((\w{1:4}\:\w{1-4)\)` for symbol. Analyze the date using delorean maybe

Comment: Thanks, to be honest any date that isn't of the format 'mmm dd yyyy' can be discarded. The real thing im trying to solve is aligning the stories with the dates I can parse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve your question using `dateparser`, a natural language date parser, and 2 different regexes. Hopefully it'll be enough.

First, install `dateparaser`:

```
pip install dateparser
```

Then run the code:

```
import collections, re, dateparser
Stock = collections.namedtuple("Stock", ["name", "symbol", "headlines"])

# Remember, '.' is not multiline, equiv to '[^\n]+'
headline_re =re.compile(r"\n\n ?\n(?P<headline>.+)\nBy .+?\xa0-\xa0(?P<date>[\w ,]+)")
symbol_re = re.compile(r"\(([A-Z]{1,4}:[A-Z]{1,4})\)")
input_data = {'ford-motor-co':(
    "\n\n\n\n\n\nFord Unloads More Shares in Electric-Vehicle Startup "
    "Rivian\nBy The Wall Street Journal\xa0-\xa020 hours ago\nFord sold 7 millionRivian "
    "shares at a price of $26.88, the company says. That followed an 8-million-share "
    "sale earlier in the week at about the same price.\n\n\n\n\n \nFord sells shares in "
    "EV maker Rivian for $188.2 million\nBy Reuters\xa0-\xa0May 14, 2022  (Reuters) - "
    "Ford Motor (NYSE:F) Co sold 7 million shares of electric carmaker Rivian Automotive "
    "Inc for about $188.2 million, or $26.88 apiece, the U.S. automaker said in a filing "
    "on Friday. Ford now... \n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nFord sells sh")}

stocks = []
for name, data in input_data.items():
    headlines = []
    for match in headline_re.finditer(data):
        date_str = match.group("date")
        date = dateparser.parse(date_str)
        headlines.append((match.group("headline"), date))
    symbol = symbol_re.search(data).group(1)
    stocks.append(Stock(name, symbol, headlines))
```

Output (stocks):

```
[Stock(name='ford-motor-co', symbol='NYSE:F', headlines=[('Ford Unloads More Shares in Electric-Vehicle Startup Rivian', datetime.datetime(2022, 5, 14, 20, 58, 28, 30552)), ('Ford sells shares in EV maker Rivian for $188.2 million', datetime.datetime(2022, 5, 14, 0, 0))])]
```

Do make sure the symbol regex is correct, as I'm not sure regarding the constraints in the stock market.

Comment: Thanks this worked using the above. However it looks you've edited the input data so the stock ticker and its associated news data are separated. How do I achieve this? When I swap input data for the actual dictionary object I get: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group' Thanks

Comment: @SullyMarshall I haven't edited the input data. I searched for caps letters with a colon inside parentheses. (`symbol_re`)

Comment: I got it to work. You helped a lot - thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can [re.split](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split).

The document says, `if capturing parentheses are used in pattern, then the text of all groups in the pattern are also returned as part of the resulting list`

So if you use `r'([A-Z][a-z]{2} \d{1,2}, \d{4})'`

```py
stock = 'ford-motor-co'
stock_news_table =  """\n\n\n\n\n\nFord Unloads More Shares in Electric-Vehicle Startup 
Rivian\nBy The Wall Street Journal\xa0-\xa020 hours ago\nFord sold 7 millionRivian 
shares at a price of $26.88, the company says. That followed an 8-million-share 
sale earlier in the week at about the same price.\n\n\n\n\n \nFord sells shares in 
EV maker Rivian for $188.2 million\nBy Reuters\xa0-\xa0May 14, 2022  (Reuters) - 
Ford Motor (NYSE:F) Co sold 7 million shares of electric carmaker Rivian Automotive 
Inc for about $188.2 million, or $26.88 apiece, the U.S. automaker said in a filing 
on Friday. Ford now... \n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nFord sells sh"""
date_data = re.split(r'([A-Z][a-z]{2} \d{1,2}, \d{4})' , str(stock_news_table))
headline = stock_news_table
date_data
```

will return

```
['\n\n\n\n\n\nFord Unloads More Shares in Electric-Vehicle Startup \nRivian\nBy The Wall Street Journal\xa0-\xa020 hours ago\nFord sold 7 millionRivian \nshares at a price of $26.88, the company says. That followed an 8-million-share \nsale earlier in the week at about the same price.\n\n\n\n\n \nFord sells shares in \nEV maker Rivian for $188.2 million\nBy Reuters\xa0-\xa0',
 'May 14, 2022',
 '  (Reuters) - \nFord Motor (NYSE:F) Co sold 7 million shares of electric carmaker Rivian Automotive \nInc for about $188.2 million, or $26.88 apiece, the U.S. automaker said in a filing \non Friday. Ford now... \n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nFord sells sh']
```